# Print the capture group of the first match and exit

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to get the first match's first capture group from piped input to perl. For example this prints all matches:

```
$ printf "hello\nworld" | perl -nle 'print "$1" if m/([a-z]o)/'
lo
wo
```

However,

```
$ printf "hello\nworld" | perl -nle 'print "$1" && exit if m/([a-z]o)/'
```

Does not work. How can I just get the first match?

Answer (score 2):

replace `&&` with `and`

```perl
print "$1" and exit if m/([a-z]o)/
```

Comment: Because `&&` has much higher precedence than `and`.

Comment: Specifically, it parses as `(print("$1" && exit)) if ...` rather than `(print("$1") and exit) if ...`. So the exit will run before the print, if $1 is non-empty and non-zero, and print will print out a false value (empty string) otherwise.